# does this expression look familiar (natural log with exponential)?

Tags: analysis, statistics, physics, exponential-distribution

The certain payoff in a decision problem I am solving is affected by decision variables $k$ and $n$ as follows:

$$f(k,n)= \frac{\alpha}{\lambda} \ln \left(\frac{\alpha + n e^{\frac{k}{\alpha}} }{\alpha + n}\right)$$

I am curious if similar functions exist in other literatures (I work in statistics), just to draw analogies.